Отсутствует перевод сообщения о провале переотрытия вопроса после голосования за переоткрытии правкой
Если отредактировать закрытый вопрос и отметить галочку Данная правка устраняет первоначальную причину закрытия, и следует рассмотреть возможность повторного открытия вопроса и после проверки вопрос решат оставить закрытым, то приходит такое сообщение на английском:

При этом перевод вроде уже есть. Он просто недавно добавлен или это баг?

Строка выглядит старой, от октября 2021. Вероятно, что-то в коде меняли рядом. Имеет смысл на MSE отправить запрос.

@αλεχολυτ, хорошо завтра отправлю.

@αλεχολυτ, отправил: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/401736
